# Placeholder with defaults syntax

Tags: java, maven, docker-maven-plugin

I have a `port` section in my maven file (docker-maven-plugin section) that looks like this:

```
<port>${webservice.adminport}:8080</port>
```

This works fine (uses webservice.adminport if it is defined or defaults to 8080).

However, I'm trying to use the same pattern in the `env` section of the pom:

```
<MY_ENV_VAR>http://${docker.host.address}:${webservice.adminport}:8080/my-service</MY_ENV_VAR>
```

but getting the following error, I think the syntax in the `env` section above is not correct?

Could not resolve placeholder 'webservice.adminport' in value "http://1.2.3.4:${webservice.adminport}:8080/my-service

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
<MY_ENV_VAR>http://${docker.host.address}:${webservice.adminport:8080}/my-service</MY_ENV_VAR>
```

Comment: You might want to add some text to explain the difference :)